# Pass initial value to a modelform in django

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I pass an initial value for a field to a model form. I have something like the following code

```
class ScreeningForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Screening

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScreeningForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['blood_screen_type'] =  CommaSeparatedCharField(
            label=self.fields['blood_screen_type'].label,
            initial=self.fields['blood_screen_type'].initial,
            required=False,
            widget=CommaSeparatedSelectMultiple(choices=BLOOD_SCREEN_TYPE_CHOICES)
        )

class ScreeningAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #form = ScreeningForm
    form = ScreeningForm(initial={'log_user':get_current_user()})
```

Now I want to pass an initial value for a field of the Person class. How can I do that?

Comment: you cannot instantiate a form in the Admin. The `form = ` portion must be form Class and not an form object.

Comment: but you can wrap the form in a factory

Comment: where does get_current_user() come from? I don't know this function and can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 17):

You can pass initial value to a ModelForm like this:

```
form = PersonForm(initial={'fieldname': value})
```

For example, if you wanted to set initial `age` to `24` and `name` to `"John Doe"`:

```
form = PersonForm(initial={'age': 24, 'name': 'John Doe'})
```

### **Update**

I think this addresses your actual question:

```
def my_form_factory(user_object):
    class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
        # however you define your form field, you can pass the initial here
        log_user = models.ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES, initial=user_object)
        ...
    return PersonForm

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = my_form_factory(get_current_user())
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but I got the following error.  issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Comment: where are you getting this error? `issubclass() arg 1 must be class`

Comment: admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)

Comment: Just to clarify, in your `PersonAdmin` class, are you doing `form = PersonForm(initial={'fieldname': value})? If so, what you want to do is to use default instead.

Comment: No actually, I want to initialize with a dynamic value, something like initial = {'creator':current_user}. So, the current user is dynamic and obtained from the request object

Comment: I've updated my answer, it might be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3692/discussion-between-derek-kwok-and-rajan-sthapit)

Answer (score 12):

In case anyone is still wondering, the following works to set initial values for an Admin form:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['log_user'].initial = get_current_user()
        return form
```

Note that you can also set initial values via URL parameters: e.g. */admin/person/add?log_user=me*

Answer (score 11):

As your ModelForm is bound to the Person-Model, you could either pass a Person-Instance:

```
form = PersonForm(instance=Person.objects.get(foo=bar)
```

or overwrite the ModelForm's init-method:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['foo'].value = 'bar'

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ['name']
```

This is untested. I'm not sure whether "value" is correct, I'm not having a Django-Installation here, but basically this is the way it works.

Comment: I have overridden the init method as well. But still it is throwing the same error, when I try to pass the initial parameter while initializing the form

Comment: No I mean in mymodel I have done the same thing, overridden the init method and it is throwing error

Comment: +1, thank you @schneck.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: This now should be
    `self.fields['foo'].value = 'bar'`

⇒  
    `self.fields['foo'].initial = 'bar'`