# How to instantiate a Django ModelForm with pre-filled required fields?

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

I have a subclass of `ModelForm`, `FamilyDemographicsForm`, for which two `ChoiceField`s are required: `point_of_contact` and `birth_parent`. For example, the following tests pass:

```
class FamilyDemographicsFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_empty_form_is_not_valid(self):
        '''The choice fields 'point_of_contact' and 'birth_parent' are
        the only two required fields of the form'''
        form = FamilyDemographicsForm(data={})

        # The form is not valid because the required fields have not been provided
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
        self.assertEqual(form.errors,
            {'point_of_contact': ['This field is required.'],
             'birth_parent': ['This field is required.']})

    def test_form_with_required_fields_is_valid(self):
        '''The form's save() method constructs the expected family'''
        data = {'point_of_contact': Family.EMPLOYEE,
                'birth_parent': Family.PARTNER}
        form = FamilyDemographicsForm(data=data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())

        # The family returned by saving the form has the expected attributes
        family = form.save()
        self.assertEqual(family.point_of_contact, Family.EMPLOYEE)
        self.assertEqual(family.birth_parent, Family.PARTNER)

        # The family exists in the database
        self.assertTrue(Family.objects.filter(id=family.id).exists())
```

In the second test case, a new instance of `Family` is created upon `form.save()`. I'd like to try instead to update an existing family. To get me started, I tried the following:

```
def test_update_existing_family(self):
    initial = {'point_of_contact': Family.EMPLOYEE,
               'birth_parent': Family.PARTNER}
    data = {'employee_phone': '4151234567',
            'employee_phone_type': Family.IPHONE,
            'partner_phone': '4157654321',
            'partner_phone_type': Family.ANDROID}

    form = FamilyDemographicsForm(data=data, initial=initial)
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

However, when I dropped into the debugger, I noticed that `form.is_valid()` is `False` and `form.errors` indicates that the required fields are not provided:

```
ipdb> form.errors
{'point_of_contact': ['This field is required.'], 'birth_parent': ['This field is required.']}
```

My question is: is there any way to instantiate a valid `ModelForm` with `data` that does not include the required fields? E.g. by providing an appropriate `initial` or `instance` argument? (This is not immediately clear to me from the source code for `BaseModelForm` on https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `ModelForm` and `Form` that Django provides to fit them your needs. You can override every method as you wish. The most base and essential prefill would be providing an `initial` dict with data {field_name: value, ...} that the form accepts without any modification.

So for example you have this

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and this form

```
class Model1ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('name', )
```

and you can provide the initial data in the view as

```
initial = {'name': 'Initial name'}
form = Model1ModelForm(initial=initial)
```

so name in this form will be prefilled.

django docs: [Providing initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)

stack overflow: [Pass initial value to a modelform in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513384/pass-initial-value-to-a-modelform-in-django)